# Can you _remove_ a variant from ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) in Rails, variants are added "on demand" as you create them. They are now persisted in some storage (disk, S3, google cloud, etc).

If you realize some variants are un-needed after all and change your code to not invoke them... I think they'll still be sitting persisted in storage.

How does one clean these up, so they're not taking up storage space? I can't find any ActiveStorage API to remove variants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can [delete](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L47) a file from ActiveStorage services (disk, s3 etc.) with its `key` . And a variant's [key](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb#L58) is identified by its blob and transformation. Therefore you can delete a specific variant like this:

```
avatar = user.avatar
variant = avatar.variant(resize: '100x100')
avatar.service.delete(variant.key)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the cost of generating all variants again is acceptable or if you need to invalidate most variants, then you can simply delete the *variants* folder. Rails will generate the variants again when needed.

Comment: where is the variants folder located?

Comment: @james it's located at the root of your bucket if you are using google cloud storage.