# Active Storage - How to regenerate image variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

How to do you manually reganerate a variant with active storage? Example class:

```
  class Doc
    has_many_attached :uploads do |attachable|
      attachable.variant :pdf_thumb, resize_to_limit: [400, nil]
    end
  end
```

I want to be able force the regeneration of the `pdf_thumb` from the example

Comment: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob/Representable.html#method-i-representation : "Frequently, though, you don’t actually want to transform the variant right away. But rather simply refer to a specific variant that can be created by a controller on-demand. Like so: `<%= image_tag Current.user.avatar.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>` " ... does that work the way you want?

Comment: No the variant already exists, I want to regenerate the specific variant image that's hosted on S3. I basically want to know how to do it manually

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389104/can-you-remove-a-variant-from-activestorage

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I have successfully used in production:

1. Delete the "variants" directory at the root of your bucket in the storage backend (i.e. Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage).
2. Open the Rails console and delete all variants records in the database:

   ```rb
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("delete from active_storage_variant_records;")
   ```

Rails will automatically regenerate the respective variants next time they are needed.